# Swift not treating realm results as an array

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to get realm results, then filter it with filter function. However i can't "tell" compiler that it have to treat expression result as an array. Following code not working:

```
guard (realm.objects(DBOfflineOrder.self) as Array).filter{$0.uniqueHash == newHash}.isEmpty else { return }
```

However, following work:

```
let arr: Array = realm.objects(DBOfflineOrder.self).filter{$0.uniqueHash == newHash}
guard arr.isEmpty else { return } // we dont have to add duplicates
```

What i want is, to simplify exprssion in one line, without creating local variable. Is that possible?

Comment: What about `guard 
 (realm.objects(DBOfflineOrder.self).filter{$0.uniqueHash == newHash} as Array).isEmpty else { return }` ??

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal i didn't try it, but, if my case it look like it try to use filter function that belong to realm, so, it treat realm.objects(DBOfflineOrder.self) as Realm Results, instead of Array.

Comment: try this code  `let arr:[DBOfflineOrder] = Array(realm.objects(DBOfflineOrder.self).filter({$0.uniqueHash == newHash}))`

Comment: Another thing to try: `guard (realm.objects(DBOfflineOrder.self) as Array).filter({$0.uniqueHash == newHash}).isEmpty else { return }`.  Comment: trailing closures don't work well in compound statements, so surround closure to `filter` with `()`.

Comment: I can only imagine that all of these query's are done remotely on the realm server. That's why you have a `Results` object, not an `Array`. Using an array in this case would be absolutely crazy. E.g. imagine fetching all results to the device, immediately filtering out most of them, then get the first one and ignore the rest. Think of the wasted network traffic, device processing, etc.

Comment: @Alexander it happen on device, and how would u suggest to filter results that match certain criteria? Why my approach is not good? Look like it work.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Suppose you had a database of 1000 movies, each with titles, cover art, cast, etc. Imagine your user searches for "Shrek", which pulls up 3 results. Would you rather: 1) Have the realm server scan the database, find all matches for shrek, and return the 3 results, or 2) Have the realm server send all 1000 movies to the device (wasting the user's data plan), then, using its slow processor (optimized for battery life, low heat, small size and low cost, not speed) do the crunching, yielding 3 useful results, and 997 discard records.

Comment: @Alexander but we using realm that is on device, how else i could filter unnecessary results without iterating over all of them?

Comment: Is `uniqueHash` a persisted Realm property? If so, you should be using `Realm`'s `filter` method that accepts an `NSPredicate` rather than using Swift's `filter`. Btw if you want to convert a `Results` instance to an `Array`, you should do `Array(realm.objects(DBOfflineOrder.self))` rather than casting.

Comment: @DávidPásztor what is the difference in such casting? Unique cash is computed property.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban you can only cast related types (either bridged like `Array`-`NSArray` or inheritance related ones) and `Results` and `Array` doesn't fit any of those criteria. On the other hand, you can __convert__ a `Results` instance to an `Array` by calling its designated initializer accepting a `Sequence`, which `Results` conforms to.